# Getting MAC address for a given IP from ARP entry (Linux kernel)

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I am writing a kernel module and need, for a given IP, to verify if there is an ARP entry on the ARP cache of the kernel for that IP. If it exists, I need to then fetch the MAC address from this ARP entry.

I am at this point trying to understand the `arp_find` function on `usr/src/linux-version/net/ipv4/arp.c` but I don't quite get it... Could someone please post an example of how can I accomplish this task or direct me to something that can help me out? I would greatly appreciate it!

**EDIT:** my IP address is stored as a `struct in_addr`

**EDIT #2:** I found my answer -- for those who have this problem, check the function `neigh_lookup` on `net/core/neighbour.c`. The `pkey` parameter is just a pointer to your IPv4 address (`struct in_addr`).

Comment: Hi, I would like to ask if you succeeded in your goal? I am writing kernel module which handles TCP packets in a special way and then suppose to send them out to their destination. But seems I can't get MAC address of next hop. I already have an IP address of it, but any request to rtable structure that touches mac address ends up in kernel panic....

Comment: @AlexKey: did you try what I described in "edit #2"?

Answer (score 0):

I think in Linux kernel, the ARP cache only stores the neighbor's mac addresses. You can use arp_ioctl() or follow arp_ioctl() approach to implement your task. arp_ioctl() does two major things: (1) find the net_device; (2) arp lookup;

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I needed to get the MAC address of a neighbor that is associated with specific IP. Also, in my case, it could be that IP<->MAC mapping is not presented in the ARP cache. So in that case I need to send ARP request first.

This is a *dirty* solution that I got at the moment:

```c
struct mac_addr {
    uint8_t addr[ETH_ALEN];
};

static int resolve_neighbour(__be32 const src_ip, __be32 const dst_ip, struct mac_addr* const mac) {
    int rc = 0;
    struct neighbour *neigh;
    struct rtable* const rt = ip_route_output(&init_net, dst_ip, src_ip, 0, 0);

    if (IS_ERR(rt)) {
        LOG(KERN_ERR, "Failed to find ip route"); // TODO: add dst and src ip
        return PTR_ERR(rt);
    }

    rcu_read_lock();
    neigh = dst_neigh_lookup(&rt->dst, &dst_ip);
    if (neigh) {
        if (neigh->nud_state & NUD_VALID) {
            neigh_ha_snapshot(mac->addr, neigh, rt->dst.dev);
        } else {
            PDEBUG("neigh is not valid. Sending ARP");
            if ((rc = neigh_resolve_output(neigh, NULL))) {
                LOG(KERN_ERR, "Failed to resolve neighbour");
            } else {
                rc = -EAGAIN;
            }
        }
        neigh_release(neigh);
    } else {
        LOG(KERN_ERR, "Failed to get neighbour"); // TODO: add dst ip
        rc = -ENONET;
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();
    return rc;
}

static int foobar(void) {
    int rc = 0;
    __be32 const dst_ip = 0x0a01000a; // FIXME: TODO: get it from register or from tre user
    __be32 const src_ip = htonl(0); // FIXME: TODO: get it from register or from the user
    struct mac_addr mac;
    size_t i;
    enum {RESOLVE_TRIES = 3, RESOLVE_TIMEOUT_MS = 100};

    for (i = 0; i < RESOLVE_TRIES; ++i) {
        if ((rc = resolve_neighbour(src_ip, dst_ip, &mac)) == -EAGAIN) {
            msleep(RESOLVE_TIMEOUT_MS);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (rc) {
        LOG(KERN_ERR, "Failed to get neighbour MAC address");
        return rc;
    }

    PDEBUG("DST MAC %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X",
            mac.addr[0], mac.addr[1], mac.addr[2],
            mac.addr[3], mac.addr[4], mac.addr[5]);

    return rc;
}
```